How to wire a second garage door opener
The contractor left a wire hanging out of the wall. Told me it was for a second garage door opener. How do I go about doing that? How do I know if the wire is hot?

You always believe a wire is hot till you test it.  A non contact voltage tester is first or turn off main breaker.  Leaving a hot wire loose is not recommended and can get the contractor in hot water with their license.  Pictures of the wire/s and opener will help with connecting it up.

The wire coming out of the wall is probably for a push button switch that would open and close the additional garage door. That same wire should exit the ceiling where the motor and control board for the new opener would be. It should not be hot but needs to be verified with a multi meter. There should also be a 120V outlet in the ceiling to plug the new opener into.

If it looks like door-bell wire (very thin) it's for a wired remote button, and that (and instructions) will be supplied with your new door opener.
It will not be live until the other end is connected to the opener an even then it will only be live with a safe low voltage like 12V
